# Ko model persistence

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a question about memory allocation, and consumption, for knockout models, associated to a particular DOM element.

Let's say I have an html element, and I set a ko model for it. Then I destroy the element with JQuery's remove().
Then I create another element, with same div, and associate again the same old model.

The questions: is the model of the first element deactivated on element removal?
Is the old model still active when I create the new element with same ID, and does it handle new element's events as it did for the old one?
Using cleanNode does change this behaviour?

Comment: The model doesn't change when an element is deleted, nor does a model have any state of active or inactive in the sense you are describing. Though the event bindings might get deleted causing the model no longer to be updated/synced, depending if KO uses delegate bindings. When an element is deleted all direct bindings on that element are too. When a **new** element is created with the same id, attributes and properties, etc.. the previous bound events are **not** there anymore unless the bindings were delegate bindings on a parent element. This should be easy to test in a simple jsFiddle.

Comment: You shouldn't remove bound elements with jQuery, that's what the `with`, `if` and `template` bindings are there for

Comment: With, if and template do not remove any binding, they just alter visibility of view based on model properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2: Got a bit mixed up in method naming. When I was talking about ko.cleanNode, actually I was thinking of ko.removeNode (which calls cleanNode internally). So everywhere below where I type cleanNode, read removeNode instead.

François Wahl answered most of your questions in a comment, so I will not answer them again. But perhaps the most important question remains unanswered: does using (ko.)cleanNode change this behaviour? Yes it does, at least partially. cleanNode provides (custom) bindings with a hook to unbind event handlers, and do all sorts of other cleanup. If you have to worry about that sort of thing, removing dom nodes should always be done with ko.cleanNode, and never with jQuery.

However, using cleanNode does not guarantee everything is cleaned up nicely. As I kind of already said, in a custom binding, you still have to respond to the proper event:

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
    // Clean me up!
});
```

Edit: to cleanup a viewmodel, I find it's usually best if you implement some sort of lifetime cycle on your viewmodels (so you also get activate/dispose hooks and such). A 'view manager' could then handle loading views/viewmodels and disposing of them. For inspiration, check out the Durandal framework which does this quite nicely.

Comment: So, cleaning a node, then Jquery-removing it, recreate it and reassociate the same model than before to the same (new) div, does cause memory leaks, if there are custom binding not properly implemented with custom addDisposeCallback method implemented?

Comment: It could cause memory leaks. Suppose the custom binding sets up an event handler, but fails to remove it because it didn't add a dispose callback where the event handler is unbound, you would be leaking memory (quite a bit actually, as I found out myself when I started running into performance issues). Of course this is just one example. There are a number of things a custom binding could do that uses up memory and has to be 'freed' manually. The browser's profiling tools can help you detect the biggest problem areas (take two heap snapshots and compare)

Comment: Oh, by the way: Instead of using ko.cleanNode and then jQuery.remove, you can just use ko.removeNode. I was thinking about ko.removeNode when I typed my answer, so I've edited the answer now to reflect my error.

Comment: It is clear. Thanks for ko.removeNode()... didn't remember about it